# error report for incorrect patent number retrieval

Tags: error

Google patents fails to look up patents based on a query number
Example 9,498,155 how do i report this and get it fixed. This error has occurred at least 15 times for patent number that i have attempted to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Stackexchange and google patents are linked for discussions but are completely different entities.  I suggest [google patents FAQ](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6390996?hl=en)

And then maybe [Google support](https://support.google.com/).